# WebApi Multiple-Action Routing not working with AngularJs Attribute-Based Routes

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get the following code to route to actions on a self-hosted WebApi controller (ResourcesController), but the routing will not route to the Delete method *as well as* the GetAllResources method. It works with only one method, but not with both.  I am using Attribute-Based routing. Any help gladly accepted!

1. Using the following Web-Api Self-Hosting startup code:

   using DomainEntities;
   using Owin;
   using WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp;

   namespace ResourcesWebApiHost
   {
       public class Startup
       {
           public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
           {
                   var webApiConfiguration = ConfigureWebApi();
                   app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
           }

   ```
       private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
       {
           var config = new HttpConfiguration();
           var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:5000/", "*", "*");
           config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
           config.EnableCors();
           config.Filters.Add(new CrossDomainAccessFilter());
           config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
           return config;
       }

       public class CrossDomainAccessFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
       {
           public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
           {
               var routes = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData();
               base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
           }

           public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
           {
               if (actionExecutedContext.Response.Content != null)
               {
                   actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "null");
                   actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                   actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Using the following Controller:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Net.Http;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Web.Http;
   using DomainEntities;
   using Interfaces;
   using ResourceManagerService;

   namespace ResourcesWebApiHost
   {


   public class ResourcesController : ApiController
   {
       [Route("api/Resources/GetAllResources")]
       [HttpGet]
       public List<Resource> GetAllResources()
       {
           var service = new Service();
           return service.GetAllResources();
       }

       [ActionName("api/Resources/Delete")]
       [HttpPost]
       public HttpResponseMessage Delete(List<Resource> resources)
       {
           var service = new Service();
           var success = service.Delete(resources);
           var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,                  success.ToString());
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Using the following AngularJs code:

   var appUrl = "http://localhost:5001/api/Resources";
           var model = {};

   ```
       var resourcesApp = angular.module("resourcesApp", []);

       resourcesApp.run(function ($http) {
           $http.defaults.headers.put = {
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With'
           };
           $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

           $http.get('http://localhost:5001/api/Resources/GetAllResources').success(function (data) {
               model.resources = data;
           }).error(function (data, status) {
               alert('ERROR ' + (data || 'No Error Description'));
           });
       });

       resourcesApp.filter("selectedItems", function () {
           return function (items) {
               var resultArr = [];
               angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                   if (item.mustDelete == true) {
                       resultArr.push(item);
                   }
               });
               return resultArr;
           }
       });

       resourcesApp.controller("resourcesCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
           $scope.theModel = model;
           $scope.close = function () {
               window.close();
           }
           $scope.deleteSelectedItems = function () {
               $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
               $http.post('http://localhost:5001/api/Resources/Delete', $scope.theModel.resources);
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding the [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] header to my controller class.  The new code looks as follows:

```
namespace ResourcesWebApiHost
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ResourcesController : ApiController
    {//...more code follows...
```

I was using [CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors) for cross-origin requests, but I implemented only the configuration part - I omitted to add the attribute to the class, which completes the enable-CORS implementation.

For further information, this problem concerns the ASP.Net WebApi routing system, and has nothing to do with the AngularJS code.